# Evaluate a sum with binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k k \binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

$$\text{Find} \ \ \sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k k \binom{n}{k}^2$$

I expanded the binomial coefficients within the sum and got $$\binom{n}{0}^2 + \binom{n}{1}^2 + \binom{n}{2}^2 + \dots + \binom{n}{n}^2$$
What does this equal to? I think this can help me evaluate the original sum.

Comment: When you "expanded" you seem to have lost the $(-1)^kk$ parts.

Comment: I'm just trying to see what the binomials equal to, I didn't expand the whole thing :(

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the latter sum equals ${2n\choose n}$.

Comment: See http://www.amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic1/1c/1c_2content_7.html

Comment: @Jonas Meyer How can I prove that?

Comment: Alexander Jones: See the link in my last comment.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: You can also use [Vandermode's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity) on $\binom{n}{r}\binom{n}{n-r}=\binom{n}{r}^2$

Comment: What should I do next :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use $k\binom{n\vphantom{1}}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}=n\binom{n-1}{n-k}$
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kk\binom{n}{k}^2
=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{n-k}\tag{1}
$$
Next compute a generating function. The sum we want is the coefficient of $x^n$
$$
\begin{align}
n\sum_{m,k}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{m-k}x^m
&=n\sum_{m,k}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{m-k}x^{m-k}x^k\\
&=n\sum_k(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(1+x)^{n-1}x^k\\
&=n(1+x)^{n-1}(1-x)^n\\
&=n\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-1}(1-x)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
The sum we want is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(2)$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kk\binom{n}{k}^2
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
n\binom{n-1}{n/2}(-1)^{n/2}&\quad\text{if $n$ is even}\\[6pt]
n\binom{n-1}{(n-1)/2}(-1)^{(n+1)/2}&\quad\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{array}\right.\\[6pt]
&=n\binom{n-1}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This has been verified for $0\le n\le200$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{ Hint: }\sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k{n\choose k}^2=(-1)^m{2m\choose m},\ m=\frac{n}{2},\ \forall n: 2\mid n$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$\sum^{n}_{k=0}(-1)^k{n\choose k}^2=0,\ \forall n:2\nmid n$$

Comment: There should be a K in the sum.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm just saying that this might help ...

Comment: Ok, yes, I fixed my answer since its only an AP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Following the logic in my answer, this sum is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $\left(1-x^2\right)^n$ (which gives the answer you cite).

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done using a basic complex variables technique.
Start as in @robjohn's answer. Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k k {n\choose k}^2
= \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k k {n\choose k}
\\= \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k k \frac{n}{k} {n-1\choose k-1}
= n \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k  {n-1\choose k-1}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$${n-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^k} (1+z)^{n-1} \; dz.$$

This gives the following integral for the sum
$$\frac{n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{z^k} (1+z)^{n-1} \; dz
\\= \frac{n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1+z)^{n-1} 
\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{z^k} \; dz
\\= \frac{n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1+z)^{n-1} 
\left(-1 + \left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^n \right) \; dz$$

We may drop  the $-1$ because it participates in a product that is
entire.  This leaves
$$\frac{n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{(z-1)^n}{z^n} \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1-z) (1+z)^{n-1} \frac{(1-z)^{n-1}}{z^n} \; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n n}{2\pi i} 
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} (1-z) \frac{(1-z^2)^{n-1}}{z^n} \; dz.$$

It follows that the value of the sum is given by
$$(-1)^n n [z^{n-1}] (1-z) (1-z^2)^{n-1}.$$

For $n$ even  the $z$ from $1-z$ participates and for  $n$ odd the one
participates.

We have for $n$ even the result
$$(-1)^n n \times (-1) (-1)^{(n-2)/2} {n-1\choose (n-2)/2}
= n \times (-1)^{n/2} {n-1\choose n/2-1}
\\= n \times (-1)^{n/2} {n-1\choose n/2}$$
and for $n$ odd
$$(-1)^n n \times (-1)^{(n-1)/2} {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}
= n \times (-1)^{(n+1)/2} {n-1\choose (n-1)/2}.$$

Joining these two terms we obtain
$$n \times (-1)^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} {n-1\choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}.$$

A trace as to when this method appeared on MSE and by whom starts at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792567/).